# how to remove the whole script tag content from the fetched json data using JSON API?

Tags: javascript, json

Problems encountered when fetching data using JSON API:

The request method I used is: "http://www.example.org/?json=get_post&post_id=47. "

However the returned JSON file comes with a `<script>` block, which caused a problem :

```
            <script>
        document.cookie="kentopvc_22238=yes";
        </script>

                    <script>
        document.cookie="kentopvc_22238=yes";
        </script>

        {"status":"ok","post":{"id":22238,"type": ........... }
```

[error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLbY6.png)

Comment: The error then is with the server application that responds to the request. Is it yours?

Comment: The server is returning you a malformed JSON content. The last bit of content which has the `{..}` looks like the actual content it should be returning but not the top bit with those HTML tags. Do you own the server? If you dont, then you probably need to workaround it by just capturing the `{...}` JSON bit out of the string

Comment: I would contact whoever owns the site and ask them to fix their API

Comment: Hi, it's a wordpress site, and I did use the kentopvc plugin to count the views of each article. I believe the script block has something to do with the kentopvc plugin and maybe i should just shut it down. but, if i really the count the views of my site, can i remove the script block without shutting down the plugin? Can i use some javascript filter method the remove the <script> block in the angular js end? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the API that's returning the malformed data, you'll need to capture the string with Regex and then parse it.

```
var jsonString = response.match(/^{.*$/m)[0]
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

regex explanation

```
/    // beginning of pattern
^    // starts at the beginning of a new line
{    // looks for a bracket immediately following a new line
.*   // any subsequent characters
$    // until we reach the end of the line
/    // end of pattern
m    // the 'multiline' flag, necessary for the use of ^

[0]  // match() returns matches in an array. we want the first (and in this case only) match
```

Comment: Hi, i know why the api returns malformed data, it's a wordpress site, and I did use the kentopvc plugin to count the views of each article. I believe the script block has something to do with the kentopvc plugin and maybe i should just shut it down. but, if i really the count the views of my site, can i remove the script block without shutting down the plugin? Can i use some javascript filter method the remove the <script> block in the angular js end? thanks